# LDAP configuration for Gerrit?

Tags: ldap, gerrit

Since google has stopped the openID support for gerrit, i am trying to use LDAP for the same now. I have IP and port number of the LDAP server. But i don't know how to start now.

I also need help to update my etc/gerrit_config file:

```
[auth]
     type = ldap

[ldap]    
     server = ldap://[IP]
     accountBase = ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
     groupBase = ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com 
     referral = follow
     accountPattern = (uid=${username})
     groupPattern = (cn=${groupname})
     accountFullName = cn
     accountMemberField = memberOf
     accountEmailAddress = mail
```

Since i am a newbie for ldap, could someone please help me in the same.

Thanks!!

Comment: Does that config reflect the attributes that are used in your LDAP directory?

Comment: @StephenKing my first doubt is..my ldap server is one some other machine and i am installing gerrit on other, so do i need to install something on gerrit server as well. Sorry for my silly question!!

Comment: So you are also the admin of the LDAP server? The question is not silly, but I think you should get some basic knowledge about LDAP, if you don't have that, yet. It might be hard to explain all the eventualities (and I admit that I'm also not an expert there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At work I am running a gerrit instance that uses one of our work LDAPs for authentication. I use a configuration like this:

```
[ldap]
        server = ldap://xxx.OurDomain.com
        username = CN=ldapread,DC=OurDomain,DC=com
        password = NotShownHere
        accountBase = DC=OurDomain,DC=com
        groupBase = DC=OurDomain,DC=com
```

The key point is that you need an LDAP user that is permitted to read from the LDAP and put the coordinates of that user into the config.

In our case, I obtained these coordinates from a know to work Apache httpd config file. In your case, you may have to ask your LDAP admin for suitable credentials.

Comment: Does your LDAP groups show up in gerrit under the list groups?

Comment: No. For our setup, the groups showing up under list groups are user groups we created in gerrit with manual assignment of users to the groups. I do not know whether the ldap plug is in principle able to make ldap groups visible in gerrit.